# What is the minimum caliber required to destroy a fighting machine?

Tags: war-of-the-worlds

No specific caliber is mentioned in the novel (from what I've found), and the Live Musical shows generic cannons. Is there any specific gun used? From what I've found on the internet these 2 guns were in service with the Royal Armed Forces: a 4.7-inch naval gun on top, and 12-pounder artillery cannon below.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chapter 17 describes how the torpedo ram Thunder Child destroys two of the Martian fighting machines, the second via ramming as it exploded, but the first seemingly mostly by firing its guns:

> A flicker of flame went up through the rising steam, and then the Martian reeled and staggered. In another moment he was cut down, and a great body of water and steam shot high in the air. The guns of the Thunder Child sounded through the reek, going off one after the other, and one shot splashed the water high close by the steamer, ricocheted towards the other flying ships to the north, and smashed a smack to matchwood.

Assuming that Thunder Child is actually an ironclad torpedo ram as described, we can look at the armaments of [HMS Polyphemus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMS_Polyphemus_(1881)), the only ironclad torpedo ram the Royal Navy actually owned at this time. In the 1880s when War of the Worlds was written, her guns were "6 single Hotchkiss 3-pounder (47mm) quick-firing guns." So this calibre would at least appear sufficient to destroy a Martian fighting machine.